# How to find the velocity of 2 objects after an explosion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision

I am learning Momentum collisions at the moment and stuck on a problem I don't know how to solve.

There is an object that moves on 1 dimension (y axis) and at some point explodes and split into 2 identical masses. 1 object flies straight up and the other straight down.

I need to find the velocities of the 2 objects after the explosion.

I found the velocity of the first object a moment before the explosion.

I tried solving this by saying that there is a preservation of momentum with the object before the explosion and the 2 objects after it. - it leaves me with 2 variables.

then I tried to write an equation of the conservation of energy of the same system but got stuck, got 2 results to each velocity and came out confused.

Is there any trick here I don't see? or where did I go wrong?

Comment: It would help if you provided the full problem statement.

Comment: You need more information. Momentum conservation just promises a symmetric momentum transfer, but how big that transfer is depends on the explosion power (the separation force, the momentum transfer time etc.). Do you have a full task description with some data on this or some specific circumstances that allow you to derive this information?

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any trick here I don't see? or where did I go wrong?

From the information you provided, the only principle you can apply here is the *conservation of momentum*

$$m v = \frac{m}{2} v_1' - \frac{m}{2} v_2'$$

from which it follows $v = \frac{1}{2} (v_1' - v_2')$, where $v$ is velocity just before the explosion and $v'$ are velocities just after the explosion. The *conservation of energy* will not help much here because you do not know how much of *internal energy* is converted to kinetic energy.

---

To understand this problem, consider much simpler example: two ice skaters, initially at rest, are pushing each other off. Their velocity after they are no longer in contact depends on how hard they push (*internal force*). Since net external force on the system of two ice skaters is zero, the *system momentum* is conserved and center of mass of the system will remain at rest. I emphasize here the word **system**, which includes both ice skaters.